# "Curious as to who" vs. "curious of who"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, conjunctions

> - I'm curious as to who you are.
> - I'm curious of who you are.

The person is anonymous and I'm just wondering who it is.

Answer (score 1):

I'm curious as to who you are. (correct)

I'm curious about you. (correct)

"curious of" is possible as a collocation but not in your example.

**Example**

"The most curious of the three sculptures was a depiction of a three-headed serpent."